# vscode isn't starting pipenv properly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pipenv

I'm trying to get vscode to use my pipenv environment. When I run my code from inside a pipenv shell it works fine. When vscode runs it fails to find any of my packages.
Below is the vscode Terminal output. If I run this on a command line I get the same problems as vscode - so at least that's consistent.

The pipenv path below is correct but the invocation is wrong. What do I need to fix in my configuration?

```
/usr/bin/env 
    /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/workflowy_2_obsidian-12Fbw0_6/bin/python 
    /home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 
    40349 -- /home/user/workflowy_2_obsidian/wkfly2obsidian.py
```

.vscode/launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code into your setting.json:

```
"python.venvPath": ".../virtualenvs" #your pipenv's path
```

Then restart vscode, "CTRL+SHIFT+P" and choose the correct python interpreter.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that didn't change the outcome.  VScode finds and lets me select the right pipenv but the result is still the same command string (see original question). Those commands don't properly setup the environment.  

Reprise: pipenv shell successfully runs my code and finds all the libraries. The command string used by vscode fails to find the libraries.

Comment: @Jeremy Woodland Choose "Powershell" terminal and try again.

Comment: Clarification: I'm running on Ubuntu.

Comment: ... and I now see that Powershell is available on Ubuntu. I'll give it a kick.

Comment: Getting closer to a solution. vscode is labelling my pipenv as a venv. Interpreter options from other projects labelled as pipenv run my code properly.   I'll try destroying the current project's pipenv and recreating it.